# What is the meaning of equation of state of system: $F(p,V,T)=0$?

Tags: thermodynamics, classical-mechanics

I am studying thermodynamics at a beginners level. I just can't understand what $F(p,V,T)=0$ means mathematically and how should I read this equation.
p=pressure
V=volume
T=temperature
I don't know what is F.

Comment: Could you explain what you can't understand in this equation?

Comment: Are you saying that you don't understand the mathematical meaning of function F(argument) notation?

Comment: Is $p$ in your equation pressure or density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing the context, I'd assume this means the pressure $p$, volume $V$ and temperature $T$ are connected by a relationship $F(p,V,T)=0$. This is called an [*equation of state*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equation_of_state), and implies the three variables are not independent quantities. i.e. you can write some function of all the variables as a single equation. Another way of saying this is simply that pressure, volume and temperature are all related.

Comment: Okay, But what is F in the equation ?And also why F(p,V,T)=0 only and not some other number.

Comment: $F$ is an arbitrary function: we're just saying that *some* function exists, see the answer by Bob D as an example of such function. Also note that you could always rewrite $f(p,V,T) = c$, where $c$ is some constant, by defining a different function (as we said, it is arbitrary) like $F(p,V,T) = f(p,V,T) - c = 0$. The point is that you can write some equation, it doesn't matter how complicated or what it looks like, that contains all three variables $p$, $V$ and $T$.

Answer (score 0):

How about the function

$$F(p,V,T)=pV-RT=0$$

From the ideal gas law for one mole of gas

$$pV=RT$$

Hope this helps.